# Отображение больших картинок

Tags: java, android

Столкнулся с тем, что не отображается картинка (в качестве фона или `ImageView`).

Размеры 650 * 5675 ~4.68Мб. 
Задача: Установить картинку как фон для `NavigationDrawer` `a. Сама вьюха разделена на 5 условных частей, и картинка тоже разделена. Соответственно, при нажатии на элементы списка, картинка прокручивается до нужной позиции.

- Элемент списка 1 (Синий цвет фона)
- Элемент списка 2 (Зеленый цвет фона)
- Элемент списка 3 (Красный и тд)

Рисунок фона, перетекает сверху вниз, т.е. если сейчас фон синий, то видно часть зеленого фона.

**p.s.** цвета привел для примера. (В реальности акварельная клякса перетекает от 1 к другому цвету)

**UPD**: В логе вижу сообщение :

> Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (640x5675,
>   max=4096x4096)

**UPD 2**: Ужал картинку до 1.25Мб: В логе все тоже. Значит ли это, что в любом случае на слабых телефонах будет     `OutOfMemory`

**UPD 3:**  Изображение отображается,я изменил формат картинки. Изначально картинка была в формате `PNG`, мы ее сжали до размера 1.25Мб и сохранили в `JPEG`.

Тем не менее, в логах до сих пор пишется про большой размер изображения, что видимо приведёт к `OutOfMemory` на более слабых (чем тот, на котором разрабатывается программа) устройствах.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawerContentFrame"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/long_3_small"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_bg"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**Итог:** Ужал картинку по высоте с 640x**5675**,
 до 640x**4096**. Приложение не падает, в логах чисто.

Тем не менее, не думаю, что это панацея. Если будут какие-то баги, буду писать сюда.

Comment: а нет ли в логах чего-то вроде    WARN/OpenGLRenderer(20641): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (3016x1996, max=2048x2048)

Comment: @metalurgus, да вот, увидел подобное сообщение
     
    Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (640x5675,      max=4096x4096)
Что же делать?

Comment: Извращаться как-то придется... Например, разделить картинку на 10 штук, и подгружать их, когда нужно, при прокрутке. Можно использовать ListView, должно упростить загрузку

Comment: Да и вообще, картинка в памяти займет где-то 15 (или 30, точно не помню) мб, что на более слабых дивайсах стопудово повлечет за собой OutOfMemory.

Comment: размер картинки не имеет значения, только ее разрешение. Расчитать память можно по формуле *ширина х высота х 4*

Comment: Покажите XML лейаут как вы кладете картинку в `ImageView` или код если это происходит программно.

Comment: @Barmaley обновил

Comment: Попробуйте задать ширину в `<FrameLayout>` как `match_parent` - такое ощущение, что он картинку кажет во всю ширину

Comment: @Barmaley ничего не изменилось. Еще сильнее уменьшил высоту исходной картинки (с 640x5675 до 640x4096). Сейчас в логах чисто. Изображение видно

Answer (score 1):

Варианты решения:

1. положить картинку в каталог `drawable-nodpi`
2. если это не поможет тогда вручную загружать картинку при этом скаля ее в минус
3. положить исходную картинку меньшего разрешения, или разделить ее на несколько частей

Comment: в том-то и дело, что она нужна как раз в полном разрешении, как прокручивающийся фон меню (я так понял)

Answer (score 0):

Лучше отключить загрузку фона в XML, а програмно определять размер drawer-а и грузить фон уже в нужном разрешении, как это правильно делать, описано здесь:
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
Это будет самое верное решение с точки зрения потребления памяти.